# How to add PreferenceActivity to fragment activity

Tags: android-studio

I have a class Fragment1 1) and I want to extend also PreferenceActivity to add 2) so as to include in my fragment 1) a menu preference.any ideas on how to implement it

1.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    if(container == null){
        return null;
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main1, container, false);
}

}
```

2)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pred_general);
```